# How to parse an academic degree into a category?

Tags: database, algorithm, sorting, mapping, matching

I have a list of academic degree's that I need to chategorize into the following:

```
| High School               |
| Some College              |
| Associate Degree          |
| Bachelors Degree          |
| Masters Degree            |
| First Professional Degree |
| Doctoral Degree           |
```

So say I have a string "Master of International Affairs", that would map to "Masters Degree".

Is there any comprehensive algorithm that would allow me to do this? The list of actual academic degrees seems to grow every day. I thought about Making all the Masters match to any string starting with "M" but that seems hacky.

I most probably would need to get a database of this sort from somewhere.

Comment: If by comprehensive you mean 100% correct, there's obviously no way to map randomly generated "titles" to a set number of actual categories. If you need to do something like this, a machine learning approach seems like it would be the most promising.

Comment: Have you checked wikipedia [Master's list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_master%27s_degrees) for the start ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked with the examination council of my faculty for some time, we have wished dearly for such a list and never found one. Especially not one that is applicable internationally. I say that this problem is unsolved and, with the current and future state of academia, unsolvable.

There is always some stupid course somewhere that the list does not contain.